# How does the syntax for overloading post-increment operator in c++ work?

Tags: c++

```
int operator++(int){
  //relevant code
}
```

I dont seem to understand the workings of the code for overloading post increment operator given
above

I know that the int as a dummy parameter is given to differentiate between pre-increment and post increment operator overloading.

If `a` is a object of the class in which these operators are overloaded ,both `++a` and `a++` should have a equivalent representation as `a.operator++()`(as per my understanding ),how does the int parameter  help in resolving it as a post increment operator?

-A c++ beginner

Comment: The answer is in the question :)

Comment: Well, `a++` is equivalent to `a.operator++(0)` (not sure whether the `int`'s value is specified or not).

Comment: The compiler accepts `operator++()` as well as `operator++(int)`. As you stated yourself, the `(int)` is just a dummy parameter to distinguish them. If the compiler recognizes `++a` and `a` is of a class type, it will look for `operator++()` in this class definition. If it's not overloaded it yields an error. Similar for `a++`, except it's looking for `operator++(int)`. That's it.

Comment: You can't overload this operator for `int` type (based on return type). Please provide [mcve], then with such example I'm pretty sure it will be easier for you to understand how it works (implementation is important for understanding that).

Comment: Anyway if you are a beginner, do not bother to learn operator overloads now. I know this is nice shiny feature of the language, but it is fools gold. If you master other basic features (like define own functions) and then come back to operators overload, then it will take you 3 minutes to understand.

Comment: @Quentin got it.

Answer (score 0):

> If a is a object of the class in which these operators are overloaded
> ,both ++a and a++ should have a equivalent representation as
> a.operator++()(as per my understanding ),how does the int parameter
> help in resolving it as a post increment operator?

The post increment operator *can* be called with a dummy `int` argument but normally this isn't what you would do. In the following, typically you would define `void foo::operator++(int)` so that you can make a call like (1) but (2) is legal.

```
#include<iostream>

struct foo {

    void operator++() {
        std::cout << "pre\n";
    }

    void operator++(int) {
        std::cout << "post\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    foo a;

    // these yield: pre
    ++a;
    a.operator++();

    // these yield post:
    a++;                  // (1)
    a.operator++(int{});  // (2)
}
```

Comment: Both `operator++` methods should not return `void`. One should have the return type `foo` (returns a copy) and the other `foo &` (returns a reference to `*this`)

Comment: yes, this is StackOverflow code written to be terse.

Answer (score 0):

When the compiler sees `++a`, and `a` is not a built-in type, then the compiler looks for either `a::operator++()` or `operator++(a&)` and if found then calls it.

When the compiler sees `a++`, and `a` is not a built-in type, then the compiler looks for either `a::operator++(int)` or `operator++(a&, int)` and if found then calls it.

See [Increment/decrement operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) on [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com) for more details.